# Event not being limited

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Hello guys I'm using full calendar for my calendar. The problem I'm facing right now is I'm populating all of the events in my calendar. Now for instance if I have 10 events on a day it will all those events rather then showing 4 events and then giving a plus event to see all the other event. I can't understand why am I facing this problem. Please tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong. Here is the code through which I'm populating my event:

```
viewRender: function (view) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url +"apps/calendar/getByMonth",
        async : false,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {'type': $('#formName').val() },
        success: function(mark_up){

          mark_up = JSON.parse(mark_up);

        $.each(mark_up["task"], function() {
            this.start = this.end;
        });
          my_events = mark_up["task"];
        console.log(my_events);
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents');
               $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', my_events);
        }
    });
    }
```

When the calendar then I make a ajax call to get all the events and then assign those events to `my_events`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below parameter in your fullcalendar configuration

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventLimit: 4, // Here
    viewRender: function (view) {
        // Your code mentioned in your question.
    }

});
```

This is just an example to place eventLimit.
This works for me.

Comment: where should I put it ?

Comment: I have placed it and it works but when I click +2 more it shows all. I don't all of them to come just the hidden one. Is it possible ?

Comment: No, it's fullcalendar's default behaviour.

Comment: there is no way to override it ?

Comment: No, not right now. Let's see if fullcalendar team provide is in future release.

Comment: You can handle the displaying of events yourself with [eventLimitClick](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/eventLimitClick/) which has a callback option, parameter cellInfo has a property hiddenSegs that contains the items not initially shown

Answer (score 1):

It's the full calendar default.

see

> http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/eventLimit/
>
> eventLimit 2.1.0 Limits the number of events displayed on a day.
>
> Boolean, Integer. default: false

Usage

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventLimit: true, // for all non-agenda views
    views: {
        agenda: {
            eventLimit: 6 // adjust to 6 only for agendaWeek/agendaDay
        }
    }
});
```

Just use it as false.

I don't know which version you'r using, but it's strange that it isn't `false` as default.